# PostgreSQL 11 error: column p.proisagg does not exist

Tags: postgresql, functions, centos-7

Using **phpPgAdmin v5.6** and **PostgreSQL v11.2** on **CentOS v7**, when I try to access the `Functions` tab within the `public` schema, I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist
LINE 18:    WHERE NOT p.proisagg
                      ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "p.prolang".
Dans l'instruction :

            SELECT
                p.oid AS prooid,
                p.proname,
                p.proretset,
                pg_catalog.format_type(p.prorettype, NULL) AS proresult,
                pg_catalog.oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes) AS proarguments,
                pl.lanname AS prolanguage,
                pg_catalog.obj_description(p.oid, 'pg_proc') AS procomment,
                p.proname || ' (' || pg_catalog.oidvectortypes(p.proargtypes) || ')' AS proproto,
                CASE WHEN p.proretset THEN 'setof ' ELSE '' END || pg_catalog.format_type(p.prorettype, NULL) AS proreturns,
                u.usename AS proowner
            FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
                INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = p.pronamespace
                INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_language pl ON pl.oid = p.prolang
                LEFT JOIN pg_catalog.pg_user u ON u.usesysid = p.proowner
            WHERE NOT p.proisagg
                AND n.nspname = 'public'
            ORDER BY p.proname, proresult

Fatal error: Call to a member function recordCount() on integer in /mnt/webdata/websites/applications/pga/classes/Misc.php on line 1949
```

**I get the same error** using the `\df` meta-command in **psql** (version 10.1 as it turns out):

```
ts_d=> \df
ERROR:  column p.proisagg does not exist
LIGNE 6 :   WHEN p.proisagg THEN 'agg'
                 ^
ASTUCE : Perhaps you meant to reference the column "p.prolang".
ts_d=>
```

The error in those queries seems to be due to a reference to `proisagg`, a column originally from the `pg_proc` table in the `pg_catalog` schema, but which no longer exists in PostgreSQL 11.
See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/release-11.html

Any way to resolve this?

Comment: I guess you need to open a defect against phpPgAdmin; their claim of support for Postgres 11 seems to be false at least in regard to  `pg_catalog.pg_proc`.

Comment: Right, thanks @mustaccio, I posted the bug there: https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/469/

Comment: Seems that this is a PostgreSQL rather than a phpPgAdmin problem. I updated my post.

Comment: Why oh why do they make catalog changes not backward-compatible

Comment: @mustaccio: If you want backward-compatible, use the information schema. Tools like `phpPgAdmin` take the fast lane and access system catalogs directly - and should keep their queries up to date ...

Comment: Tools like `psql` too, looks like

Comment: @mustaccio  Not all changes can be reasonably finagled to be backwards compatible.  So the alternative would be to give up on making improvements.  If you wish stability at the expense of progress, you can keep using the old version.

Comment: @jjanes Hard to argue with the broad statement like that. However, in this particular case nothing prevented them from leaving the original columns bloody well alone -- wouldn't have prevented progress, such as it is, one bit.

Comment: I have dealt with that change quite a bit. It's an obvious improvement in my book.

Answer (score 12):

In Postgres 11 `proisagg` was replaced with `prokind` in the system catalog [`pg_proc`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-proc.html):

> `prokind` | `char` | `f` for a normal function, `p` for a procedure, `a` for an aggregate function, or `w` for a window function

The query needs to be adapted. Like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc p
 ...
WHERE p.prokind = 'f'   -- to only get plain functions
...
```

Related:

- [How to drop all of my functions in PostgreSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/122742/how-to-drop-all-of-my-functions-in-postgresql/122777#122777)
- [PostgreSQL: How to list all stored functions that access specific table](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46995/postgresql-how-to-list-all-stored-functions-that-access-specific-table/46996#46996)

The error you observed from the `\df` meta-command in psql is most likely due to using an outdated version of psql. psql 11 and up are updated to deal with  this change, of course.

Comment: Thanks @Erwin Brandstetter. I guess psql will be corrected to reflect this change?

Comment: @SébastienClément: psql is updated, of course. Your version of psql? It's displayed on startup. (Would be instrumental in the question to begin with).

Comment: you are absolutely right. I was using psql 10.1 to connect to the server. I will update it.

Answer (score 5):

In the case of **phpPgAdmin**, you must modify the faulty queries within `\classes\database\Postgres.php`.

[pg_proc.proisagg](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/catalog-pg-proc.html) (PostgreSQL 10 and before) is a boolean set at TRUE when function is an aggregate function.

[pg_proc.prokind](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/catalog-pg-proc.html) (PostgreSQL 11) is a char taking the values 'f', 'p', 'a' or 'w' (see Erwin's answer above).

Thus, for every occurence of `WHERE NOT p.proisagg` (function is *not* an aggregate function), replace with `WHERE p.prokind <> 'a'`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and ran these 2 commands to fix it

```
sed -i "s/NOT pp.proisagg/pp.prokind='f'/g" /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/Postgres.php
sed -i "s/NOT p.proisagg/p.prokind='f'/g" /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/Postgres.php
```