# PostgreSQL 12: column proisagg does not exist

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-3

I created a PostGIS database using the following images [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/kartoza/postgis/tags) (i.e. 9.3-2.1, 11.0-2.5 and 12.0 tags), however I'm getting the following errors when I try to open the 'public' schema:

[image]

[image]

```
An error has occurred:

11:43:59: Error: ERROR:  column "proisagg" does not exist
LINE 9:  WHERE proisagg = FALSE AND pronamespace = 2200::oid
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "pr.prolang".
```

```
An error has occurred:

11:46:24: Error: ERROR:  column rel.relhasoids does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_userbyid(rel.relowner) AS relowner, rel.relacl, rel.relhas...
```

I found possible solutions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/238906/181099) and [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/phppgadmin/bugs/469/). I tried to ask how should I update the query, but I need at least 50 reputation to comment.

Would anyone know how should I fix this question? Or how should I change the definition of the query on pgAdmin?

Thanks in advance.

**System:**

- PostgreSQL 12.0 (Ubuntu 12.0-2.pgdg16.04+1)
- pgAdmin III
- Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Comment: @mustaccio Related, but no duplicate.

Comment: Yes, my question is related, but it is not duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The query is hard-coded into pgAdmin III, and you cannot change it.

These columns have been removed in v12 because they are no longer useful.

pgAdmin III has been out of support for years.

Use pgAdmin 4 or another supported client tool.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz for your explanation.