# PostgreSQL 12.5/ pgAdmin - postgis. Error: column p.proisagg does not exist

Tags: postgresql-12, pgadmin-3

pgAdminIII reports errors related with a column missing after installing postgis in postgres 12.5 and ubuntu 20.04

Error column proisagg does not exist where perhaps you meant pr.proisagg

people reported this error en previous versions and phpadmin

[PostgreSQL 11 error: column p.proisagg does not exist](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238903/postgresql-11-error-column-p-proisagg-does-not-exist)

Solution there does not work

Note /usr/share/phpPgAdmin/classes/database/ does not exist in my installation

Comment: pgAdmin 3 is not compatible with Postgres 11 or later